# Apache mod_rewrite redirect: ampersands in new query string being transformed incorrectly

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I need to rewrite a URL using Apache (2.2.31) mod_rewrite so that `page.html` becomes `another.html?a=one&b=two&c=three`. If there's query string parameters associated with `page.html` then they should be ignored. I'm trying this:

```
RedirectMatch ^/page.html.*$ "/another.html?a=one&b=two&c=three"
```

...which performs the redirect, but the ampersand characters are being transformed so that the redirected URL looks like this:

```
/another.html?a=one/page.htmlb=two/page.htmlc=three
```

I've tried replacing the `&` characters in the redirect rule query string with %26 instead, but the redirected URL displays them literally.

There's a lot of options for mod_rewrite and I'm having trouble finding the solution in the docs.

Answer (score 4):

It turned out that all I had to do was escape each of the ampersands in the rewrite rule using a backslash character e.g. `\&`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, escaping the `&` as `\&` did *not* help, because I did not want to escape the `&` directly in the query string of the page redirected to, but instead inside another URL parameter.

This is my destination URL:

```
/another.html?url=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.org%2Fpage.html%3Fa%3Db%26c%3Dd%26e%3Df
```

I.e. `/another.html` gets a query string parameter `url` with the value of

```
https://example.org/page.html?a=b&c=d&e=f
```

Based on [RTF's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33396169/107625), I was able to deduce that the `%` also needs to be escaped as `\%`.

So my final rewrite rule looked something like that:

```
RewriteRule 
    ^/page.html$ 
    "/another.html?url=https\%3A\%2F\%2Fexample.org\%2Fpage.html\%3Fa\%3Db\%26c\%3Dd\%26e\%3Df" 
    [NE,L]
```

(Line breaks inserted for readability).

**tl;dr:**

Escape `%` with `\%`.